# telegram bot send_message() hangs with HTML text

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am new to Telegram Bot API (python telegram.ext), here is my question: I am trying to send formatted message in reply to received message. For simplicity I removed everything from the code below

```
    mtxt = "<ul><li>line 1</li></ul>"
    res = bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=mtxt, parse_mode='HTML')
    print(res)
```

Nothing is returned to telegram (no answer from bot) and print() never happens. If I remove 'parse_mode...' clause from the call it works.

I must be fundamentally wrong somewhere... This is very basic staff, what is missing?

Comment: Will wrapping the mtxt in `HTML(mtxt)` will help ?  HTML is from from  `IPython.display import HTML`

Comment: I tried above code , i recieved your mtxt as plain txt , telegram app did not convert it to HTML.

Comment: wrapping in HTML is not mentioned in documentation, why should it change something in send_message() behaviour?

Comment: That is part of the question: in my case (I just tried it again) send_message() just blocks... No print() no message in telegram...

Comment: Yes, it is not mentioned in the documentation, I faced a similar issue, but it was a different scenario.

Comment: **got it** (in the answer below): nested markup is not supported, only tiny html subset is supported...

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot

Answer (score 2):

There only have [limited tags](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) :(

You can use emoji to format, or make a suggestion to [Telegram](https://twitter.com/telegram).

Comment: thank you, I think this is the answer, initially I tried Markdown with the same "success" - could not make list or bold.

Do you know Markdown telegram limitation< are they listed somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The usable tags are listed here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

If You use other tags the telegram API fails.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35283837)

Comment: You are right, but on the other hand the api probably will be extended by telegram in the future for better tag support. In this case a link to the developers website will provide a fresher answer than a outdated copy here. And btw I tried first to add the link URL as comment to the first answer, but this was denied by stackoverflow (my reputation score is to low).